# Live Writer Image Posting

Tags: blogs

I have a Blog hosted on my site, the blog engine I choose is Subtext, I'm using Windows Live Writer as a content editor. 
First of all I cannot post images in posts, and even if the posting action goes well, I cannot see images when I go on the post page. Second, how to setup Subtext to accept images well on posts?

Comment: How is this "Programming related"? Shouldn't you be asking this on the Subtext forum?

Answer (score 0):

The Subtext [forum](http://groups.google.com/group/subtext) seems pretty quiet. Try Googling [Subtext Live Writer](http://www.google.com.au/search?q=Subtext+Live+Writer), there seems to be plenty of people blogging about it :)

Comment: All the things you said I've done before, I've lost half a day googling for that..  I was hoping that ads developers, here someone could help me but maybe I was mistake